# Touch pad and touch screen are not working after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, touchpad, touchscreen, 22.04

I have laptop Acer spin 5 "Spin SP513-54N" and had ubutnu 21.10 installed on it. At first, the touch pad and touch screen were not working so I followed the instructions in this page and it fixed it:
https://sciactive.com/2020/12/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-spin-5-sp513-54n-for-the-perfect-linux-2-in-1/

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Add pci=nocrs to the end of the options for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. It should look something like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nocrs"
sudo update-grub

Later when I upgraded to ubuntu 22.04, touch pad and touch screen stopped working again
When ubuntu 22.04 starts up before applying GRUB fix, I get this error:
[image]

Ubuntu starts fine but the touch is not working. But when I apply the fix, ubuntu 22.04 fails to start with this error:
[image]

I tried every fix I could possible find online but nothing works. plz help me with this issue as the computer is not usable without touch pad

Comment: This is the reason I am staying on 20.10 - it's very unfortunate: quote: "Hans de Goede (j-w-r-degoede) wrote on 2022-05-13:   #39
Sorry that it is taking so long to fix this. There have been several attempts at fixing this upstream already, but all of them had to be reverted/dropped because they were causing issues on other laptop models...." - more in the original bugreport https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1884232

Comment: It needs to be changed in kernel. However, it is still primarily the BIOS' fault, among others - https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/636073/spin-5-sp513-54n-efi-bios-boot-cursor-cannot-be-seen#latest - but I doubt ACER would do anything about these :( So that's why it's more probable to fix via kernel update once the patch is upstream...

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the kernel to 5.18:

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-headers-5.18.0-051800_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-modules-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then everything works with `pci=nocrs`.

Comment: Are you sure upgrading to kernel v5.18 the parameter ```pci=nocrs``` works without any issue?

Comment: It works for me on my Acer Spin 5 SP513-54N.

Comment: I got the following errors:

1-
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic:
 linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.9.
 linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic depends on libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1); however:
  Package libssl3 is not installed.

2-
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

3-
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic